react js / viselect/react
My code is a React component for a scheduling grid using the @viselect/react library. It allows users to select specific hours across days in a week, with features for selecting/deselecting entire rows (days) and columns (hours).
The problem is when i select from the extra row or column it will select the specified column or row
but after i try deselect one cell from this row or column it wont only after the second click on it
export default function Scheduler({ data, onSelectionChange }) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(() => new Set());
  const [extraSelected, setExtraSelected] = useState({
    rows: new Set(),
    columns: new Set(),
  });

  const extractIds = (els) =>
    els.map((v) => v.getAttribute("data-key")).filter(Boolean).map(Number);

  const handleColumnSelect = (colIndex) => {
    const newColumns = new Set(extraSelected.columns);
    const newSelection = new Set(selected);

    if (newColumns.has(colIndex)) {
      newColumns.delete(colIndex);
      for (let row = 0; row < 7; row++) newSelection.delete(row * 24 + colIndex);
    } else {
      newColumns.add(colIndex);
      for (let row = 0; row < 7; row++) newSelection.add(row * 24 + colIndex);
    }

    setExtraSelected((prev) => ({ ...prev, columns: newColumns }));
    setSelected(newSelection);
  };

  const handleRowSelect = (rowIndex) => {
    const newRows = new Set(extraSelected.rows);
    const newSelection = new Set(selected);

    if (newRows.has(rowIndex)) {
      newRows.delete(rowIndex);
      for (let col = 0; col < 24; col++) newSelection.delete(rowIndex * 24 + col);
    } else {
      newRows.add(rowIndex);
      for (let col = 0; col < 24; col++) newSelection.add(rowIndex * 24 + col);
    }

    setExtraSelected((prev) => ({ ...prev, rows: newRows }));
    setSelected(newSelection);
  };
  const onMove = ({ selection, store: { changed: { added, removed } } }) => {
    setSelected((prev) => {
      const next = new Set(prev);
      extractIds(added).forEach((id) => next.add(id));
      extractIds(removed).forEach((id) => next.delete(id));
      return next.size !== prev.size ||
        [...next].some((id) => !prev.has(id)) ||
        [...prev].some((id) => !next.has(id))
        ? next
        : prev;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SelectionArea
        className="container"
        onMove={onMove}
        selectables=".selectable"
      >
        <div className="empty"></div>
        {Array.from({ length: 24 }, (_, index) => (
          <div className="header" key={`header-hour-${index}`}>{`${index}h`}</div>
        ))}

        {["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"].map((day, rowIndex) => (
          <div className="left-label" key={`day-${rowIndex}`}>{day}</div>
        ))}

        {Array.from({ length: 7 * 24 }, (_, index) => (
          <div
            className={selected.has(index) ? "selected selectable" : "selectable"}
            data-key={index}
            key={`grid-${index}`}
            style={{
              gridRow: Math.floor(index / 24) + 2,
              gridColumn: (index % 24) + 2,
            }}
          />
        ))}

        <div className="extra-row" style={{ display: "contents" }}>
          {Array.from({ length: 24 }, (_, colIndex) => (
            <div
              className={
                extraSelected.columns.has(colIndex) || isColumnFullySelected(colIndex)
                  ? "selected selectable"
                  : "selectable"
              }
              key={`extra-row-${colIndex}`}
              onClick={() => handleColumnSelect(colIndex)}
              style={{ gridRow: 9, gridColumn: colIndex + 2 }}
            />
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="extra-column" style={{ display: "contents" }}>
          {Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, rowIndex) => (
            <div
              className={
                extraSelected.rows.has(rowIndex) || isRowFullySelected(rowIndex)
                  ? "selected selectable"
                  : "selectable"
              }
              key={`extra-col-${rowIndex}`}
              onClick={() => handleRowSelect(rowIndex)}
              style={{
                gridRow: rowIndex + 2,
                gridColumn: 26,
                background: "black",
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </SelectionArea>
    </>
  );
}


